# generate a polygon that only keep its outside boundary

Tags: boundaries

I have 25 different polygons as show in fig. below. These small  polygons can form a bigger polygon without overlaps.

[image]

My goal is, according the data of 25 smaller polygons, to generate the bigger polygon that only keep its outside boundary.

Now I have selected the 25 polygons and saveas another file, but the innner lines are also included.

I have tried the layer-property-symbol level method, but there is no such button in my .shp file. I have no idea why.

[image]

Comment: Hello. The link to your image isn't working, in addition it would be helpful to know what language/software you're using in order to offer usable solutions.

Comment: Hi, I am now using the QGIS.

Comment: if you want to GENERATE the bigger polygon use DISOLVE (Menu: Vector-Geoprocessing-Dissolve). Otherwise follow underdarks answer in the duplicate post